# Paralleling differential amplifiers INA132 unknown & random issue

Tags: amplifier, differential-amplifier

B1=3v

B2=3.7v

Im using 2 ina132UA differential amplifiers in parallel to measure 2 batteries. (*voltage is within 5v*) (*U3, U2 may measure batteries which have different voltages*) and this is going into an STM8 which is acting as an ADC. the problem arises when I have B1 connected to U2 and nothing on U3 the output for U2 remains 0v(*Both amplifiers tested working separately*).

when I connect B2 to U3 the output is something like this: U2=0v U3=3.7v if I flip the batteries to each amplifier the output looks something like this: U2=3.7v U3=0v.

I've troubleshooted everything with my circuit but the problem still persists the even weirder part is that **Sometimes** i get decent result where both ICs are reporting actual battery voltage however **i still get 0v if only one of the batteries are connected** even at that random working state. Am I doing something wrong?

I have exactly the same circuit which is built with INA117p and it works great, though I cannot use it due to the issue with new PCB manufacturing for my device and also that it requires plus and minus voltage.

I'm continuously puzzled especially with this random behaviour of working then not working. it will always happen if I remove both and connect one at a time at random I tried many patterns of powering up the device and then connecting the second battery etc... Honestly, I will be fine with it if it can only work when both batteries are connected I don't require it to work with only one battery connected.

[image]

below is how they react when both batteries are connected. this random working state is measured too. in the non-working state, only U6 is working. (*GND is the negative probe of the multimeter.*)

If one of the INA is removed the circuit works all the time properly.
[image]
The switching circuit is optoisolated from the batteries and mosfets.

the power for INA/STM is isolated from the batteries and mosfets.

Battery Positive is common, the negatives are isolated by the mosfets.

there's a resistive load on OUT- and B+.

Comment: Are these measurement results from U1's ADC conversions, or did you actually measure the outputs of U2 and U3 with a voltmeter? Also, are these batteries isolated, or do they have connections to elsewhere in the circuit (perhaps between each other)? Ideally, your schematic should show all such elements, including the batteries and their connections elsewhere.

Comment: The fact that this works with the INA117 is a big hint at common-mode input range violation, which would happen if the batteries were connected in some way which raises/lowers their terminal potentials outside the common mode input range for the INA132. Connecting the batteries in series would have that effect, for example.

Comment: @SimonFitch These measurements are from measuring the outputs of U2 and U3.  I apologise for not including a correct schematic and now i realise the importance of that.  i will upload the correct schematic above, to explain that its basically a device which will switch the battery negative to OUT- and keep positive connected. The power source for U1 U2 U3 are isolated and from a different place not from any of the batteries.  mosfets switch between both of the battery negatives. So i assume hopefully both of the batteries will never be connected to each other.. only positive is.

Comment: Where are the battery negatives connected? They are not shown even on the newer schematic.

Comment: The battery negatives are connected at 1IN- and 2IN- and they get switched to the output which is OUT-

Answer (score 0):

Common-mode input voltage range for the INA117 is ±200V, which means that when using that device it is practically impossible for your inputs IN+ and IN- to fall outside the range of permissible input potentials, with respect to ground. Therefore, with inputs of \$V_{IN+} = +1V\$ and \$V_{IN-}=-1V\$, the INA117 will work as expected.

However, the INA132 is not so forgiving. With those same inputs, it will not behave the same way, because one of those inputs is outside the common-mode input voltage range for the device.

Since your circuit works with the INA117, but not the INA132, I suspect that the problem lies with the absolute potentials of IN- and IN+ falling outside the INA132's common-mode input voltage range.

It's not possible to define fixed input boundaries, because limits vary depending on the output, but given the device's single-ended supply of 0V and +5V you should aim to keep inputs between 0V and +10V. This is described on page 2 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina132.pdf), under "input voltage range".

I suggest you measure not only the potential difference *between* the inputs, but also their individual potentials with respect to ground, to determine if you are violating this constraint. If you want the common-mode input range to include negative potentials, then you will probably require a negative supply voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, ive checked the resistor dividers and everything, the most voltage it will see is from +0.6v to +4.2v. i kept reading the part where you suggested `but also their individual potentials with respect to ground` both INA132 are getting different non-common grounds and i have checked them all. the positive of the battery is going through a resistor divider and then the positive input of the INA132. how else would i be able to check the voltage?

Comment: I dont know but i feel like its a problem with both INA sharing the same +5v supply. if i have one of them on the exact same setup its working well as soon as i add another one then it gets weird. maybe the INA117 had dual supply so it can be paralleled? it had a circuit in the datasheet with multiple INA117 in parallel but never with INA132.

Comment: @Rasil measure between the IC's negative supply and that same IC's IN-. Tthen between the negative supply and IN+. If either measurement is less than 0, or greater than 10V, you have a problem. Even if it's greater than 5V, i'd say  something is very wrong.

Comment: yes youre 100% correct im getting totally garbage voltages.... i really don't understand these type of analogue circuits I'm sorry if i was a pain to deal with. i have only 1 battery connected to the INA and I'm getting across chip GND and IN- -6.15V and IN+ I'm getting -4.73V (*the multimeter minus probe is connected to chip GND*) and for the other chip which has nothing connected, I'm getting +9.77v +9.78v for both IN- and IN+

Comment: I have totally no idea on how to even start to fix this..

Comment: @Rasil start at the beginning. How is this circuit powered?

Comment: I had initially used a Buck converter connected to one of the batteries, which is entirely isolated. to power the INA/STM. then i removed that and used a separate power supply from the wall to power the INA/STM. both have the same problem.

Comment: @Rasil Whatever's causing the batteries to have such different potentials with respect to each other must be elsewhere, because I don't see anything here that would cause such behaviour. Can you update the question with information about what the batteries are powering, and what might cause them to not be isolated from each other?

Comment: I have updated the diagram of measured voltages. and explanations. Do you think this problem is caused by both batteries' ground becoming common? on my INA117 circuit, this results in both outputs having the same voltage.  what is really annoying is that it works sometimes when I have changed nothing just replugged the battery.